# Timeline of All Witcher Games/Books?

Tags: the-witcher, chronological-order

It's pretty easy to find the order of the main books and Witcher 1, 2, and 3, but where do Thronebreaker and the graphic novels fit in this chronology? More than anything I'm interested in the amount of time between each, so **if approximate start dates are known, their inclusion would be greatly appreciated**!

([this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/116284/what-is-the-recommended-order-for-the-books-and-the-games-of-the-witcher) is related but doesn't cover Thronebreaker and the graphic novels and doesn't have dates)

Answer (score 2):

Thronebreaker takes place during *The Time of Contempt* ("Witcher 2") and *Baptism of Fire* ("Witcher 3"). Nilfgaard launch their offence just after the Thanedd coup, attacking Dol Angra.

In the books, Lyra and Rivia, and their ally Aedirn, lose most of their armies fighting Nilfgaard in the battles of Dol Angra and the first battle of Aldersberg (which is in the game). Meve continues to fight a guerilla war after that, simply because she had lost most of her regular armies. The part in the game where Lyria lost because of betrayal isn't canon and never happens in the books.