# How should I read "The Witcher" books?

Tags: suggested-order, the-witcher

So, I have just watched the first season of *The Witcher* on Netflix and I am hooked...

I know the series is based on books and video games, and while I probably won't play the games I definitely want to read the books.

What would be the best way to do that? Publication order? In-universe chronologically?

Comment: https://booksreadingorder.com/the-witcher/

Comment: You forgot alphabetically and by length.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the recommended order for the books and the games of the Witcher?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/116284/what-is-the-recommended-order-for-the-books-and-the-games-of-the-witcher)

Comment: @Mithoron Thank you, I am kind of embarrassed I did not see that... I blame SE search because I specifically searched for [the-witcher] and [suggested-order]. Oh well!

Comment: Yeah, I knew it was somewhere, but was somehow difficult to find, while it should just pop up in "related"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Poking around, the order seems similar to [this one](https://www.ign.com/articles/2019/12/22/netflix-the-witcher-books-order-reading) in almost all cases:

> 1. The Last Wish
> 2. Sword of Destiny
> 3. Season of Storms (optional)
> 4. Blood of Elves
> 5. Time of Contempt
> 6. Baptism of Fire
> 7. The Tower of the Swallow
> 8. The Lady of the Lake

That's mostly the chronological order, although *The Last Wish* was released slightly after *Sword of Destiny*, and *Season of Storms* is a more recent release, but is set right after *The Last Wish*. It also is apparently fairly tangential to Geralt's story.

Comment: _The Last Wish_ is a book of short stories and is partly what the first season is based off of if I’m remembering correctly. As such even if it wasn’t the first book chronologically it would probably help someone coming across from the TV series.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot First season is also based on Sword and some info about earlier stuff that's actually mentioned in later books.

Comment: @Mithoron to be fair thought it might have been, only read part of that one though so wasn’t confident stating so.

Comment: I very much doubt that the TV-show is going to bother with *Season of Storms* anyway, since it's entirely unrelated to Ciri's story and the TV-show's pacing very urgently leads to continuing right with *Blood of Elves* in season 2. Also a major character from *Season of Storms* already died so it would have to be a flashback anyway.

Comment: You won't grasp everything in the epilogue of Season of Storms if you haven't read Lady of the Lake, however.