# Has Andrzej Sapkowski ever mentioned anything about writing more stories about the universe, but not necessarily about Geralt or Witchers?

Tags: the-witcher

I have read that Andrzej Sapkowski is writing a new *Witcher* book as of 2018. Has he ever mentioned a desire to build more universe, much like Tolkien has done with *The Lord Of The Rings* series? Not necessarily about Witcher's, but maybe a history of his universe or how the multiverse works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is: <s>no</s> YES. See edit below.

To quote him from one of the interviews:

> *The Witcher Saga* is closed. If there will be another book in this universe, it will be something along the lines of a prequel.

Sapkowski for a long time was of the opinion that Witcher is a closed topic. I was really surprised that he wrote *Season of Storms*, but he did, and as you mentioned he actually plans another book, which will be a prequel.

I think he personally is of the opinion that expanding the universe is boring.

I make that statement based on his words about his other series, the *Hussite Trilogy*, which he found much more to his liking, especially the research part. This is actually the reason his books are coming out so slooooowly - he is very meticulous in his research, and he said he much prefers history to mythology.

I do see him, however, one day announcing a collaboration with other writers set in  "The Witcher Universe". He very much wants to cash in on the success of it, too. Just like CD Projekt and Netflix.

## EDIT:

I stumbled recently on the interview with Sapkowski with one of the Polish sites, where he said that there will be some more material coming out soon-ish, which will be placed in The Witcher Universe. He is looking for authors for collaboration. He also announced that there will be more Geralt books, but he also clarified they definitely will be either prequels or placed in between previous books. So, there.

Comment: He's an odd fellow, he contradicts himself quite often. Like saying he thinks the game series has hurt sales, when really we all know most people got into the Witcher series because of the game, and like me have started reading the books after playing the game or even watching the Netflix series.

Comment: (...) collaboration with other writers set in "The Witcher Universe" Umm, there seems to be some idea of it becoming some "shared universe", that is total bonkers - see here what Sapek thinks about works of others: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/71224/is-there-any-meaningful-material-in-witcher-canon-that-requires-playing-games?rq=1

Comment: @Mithoron - Not sure about shared universe, but I could definitely see spin-offs of sorts, still under Sapkowski's name but written by others. To expand on the universe. But Sapkowski will never allow to continue writing about Geralt, Ciri and Yennefer, possibly Jaskier, too, so not sure what is there to write about? Other Witchers? A bit of a bummer... Though I'd like to read the *Shadow People, or the story of His Majesty's Secret Service* by **Oribasius Giafranco Paolo Reuven**, for sure...

Comment: CD Projekt Red also wished to buy the copyright from him, but he refused. (Which is quite understandable since he must be cashing in a lot of royalties even if he plans no further books, and this was before the Netflix series too.)

Comment: @Amarth Maybe. But have you seen the original show and movie? I kinda understand why Sapkowski didn't give a great chances of success to the game... Well, he was wrong, but at least now he's getting some good money.

Comment: @Villan - And you jinxed it. There is a contest of sorts now running, announced by Sapkowski, which looks for stories based on The Witcher Universe, and Sapkowski himself said there will be more books, but prequels or maybe in-betweeners.

Comment: Have you got a link to the interview? It would help your answer and might be quite interesting!

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - Looking for it, but unfortunately I have 4 devices' history to look through... But I have unique set of skills, and I will find It and I will include it...

Comment: @AcePL Jinxed sounds like a bad thing, I think it's good that he is willing to let others take the reigns. If George R.R. Martin had let others contribute his series might have actually seen an end.